# Port of entry for Schengen Long Stay Student Visa

Tags: schengen, customs-and-immigration, france, sweden

I have a query regarding my long stay student visa. I am going to apply for my long stay student visa for france from a non-eu country but I wish to enter Sweden first and stay for 10 days with a friend for tourism purpose. My question is: will it be a problem for my case as my main destination of study will be France but I will enter Sweden (Stockholm) first?
2 of the Campus France Managers have told me that it won't be a problem if I show them enough evidence and legitimate travel itinerary and travel tickets from Stockholm to France as well but they cannot advise regarding the border control in Sweden. I wish to know if someone has been through this?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

There is no particular reason why this would be a problem, if the visa is valid for the relevant period.

The whole basis of the Schengen visa system is that member countries trust each other to issue visas with validity for the entire zone. So someone going on a vacation to both Sweden and France would apply for only one visa, from the one of the two countries that is considered their "main destination". There's no reason to make it different just because the main destination is a long stay -- in fact the rules *explicitly* say that a long-stay visa qualifies you to go on short visits in the rest of Schengen.

The only unknown here is whether the French are willing to issue a visa that starts early enough for your 10-day visit to Sweden. Since long-stay visas are issued under national rules, I don't know the likelihood of that -- try asking at [Expats](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com) about that.

If you do get a visa with sufficient period of validity, simply arrive in Sweden with the same documentation and explanations about your plans ready as you would when arriving with a short-stay visa.